# getting an 'include map' from a project file?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand a program in a Keil project. It has several source and header files for its functions but they are not directly included in main file. Instead header files include other header files to finally get included in main. This makes it difficult for me to understand how each module integrates in the final project.

Is it somehow possible to get information on how these files are included in the main file? I am using cubeMX IDE and I want to make something like a block diagram for the program to better understand it.

How can I get a graphical diagram or block diagram for a C project?

Comment: This seems to be question about features in a specific software. You may have better luck in another site such as software recomendation SE or in the cube IDE site. However, if the source is in `C/C++` (or any popular language) there are IDEs which can create a tree of the functions and variables used. It is a common feature in the popular IDEs. If you want only an *include-tree* list, you may be able to write a script which recursively scans the files mentioned in `#include<filename>` statements of the source files.

Comment: +1 for the migration. However, since you use GCC, read the documentation about its option `-M` (and following) to generate rules for make. These rules are text and show any source file including the header files.